# textareafield background color not fully changing

Tags: html, css, extjs

I have added a textareafield to the panel, which by default is white as background. But I wanted to hide the white color and give it the lightblue color, so that it falls in with the panel.As you can see on the image, the top (first line) of the textareafield stays white. Does anyone has an idea of why, and how to solve this?
My code to generate the textareafield is:

```
        xtype: 'textareafield', 
        readOnly: true, 
        height: 150,
        fieldStyle: 'background-color: #DFE9F6', 
        value: warning,
        id: 'textareaField'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is still a background image that you will need to remove, too. Please try

```
xtype: 'textareafield', 
readOnly: true, 
height: 150,
fieldStyle: 'background-color: #DFE9F6; background-image: none;', 
value: warning,
id: 'textareaField'
```